# How to compress images and save quality using PHP

Tags: php, webp

I want to compress images on my website using PHP, to optimize it and make it faster on load.

So, I try to search for that, and I found a function to generate `WebP` images. It's really good to compress images and reduce the size of it and save quality.

```
$file = 'test.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefrompjpeg($file);
imagewebp($image, 'tes.webp', 80);
imagedestroy($image);
```

But, after search, I found that the WebP extension is not supported by a lot of browsers and that can make a big problem.

So, is there any solution to compress images using PHP with saving Quality?

Comment: this question is rather old. WebP has been supported by the major browsers now. You can check it out here: https://caniuse.com/webp

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `<picture>` tag:

```
<picture class="astronumerology-day-image-picture">
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="image.webp 1x">
    <img src="image.png" alt="">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at [this](http://image.intervention.io). easy to use php library. 
already have resize,compress,fit methods. You can create images for different  height × width.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// import the Intervention Image Manager Class
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

// configure with favored image driver (gd by default)
Image::configure(array('driver' => 'imagick')); 
Image::make($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

// resize image
$img->fit(300, 200);

// save image
$img->save('foo/bar.jpg');`
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are not saving the quality with the options you have set above because you are setting the quality to 80,

You can use PHP Imagick to resize images at runtime, or you could save the images as is with no compression and have a cron script perform the action or the webserver itself .

To use JPG, you can consider the following options :

```
    $compression = 80; // set from 75-85 generally
    $iMagick->setImageCompressionQuality($compression);
    $iMagick->setImageFormat("jpg");
    $iMagick->stripImage(); // saves lot by removing meta
```

Example (note this example resizes to max 1920 width):

```
$iMagick = new Imagick($file);
$iMagick->setImageResolution(72,72);
$iMagick->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
$geometry = $iMagick->getImageGeometry();
if ($geometry['height'] > 1920 || $geometry['width'] > 1080) {
    $iMagick->scaleImage(1920, 0);
    if($geometry['height'] > $resizeHeight) {
        $iMagick->scaleImage(0, 1080);
    }
}
$iMagick->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$iMagick->setImageCompressionQuality($compression);
$iMagick->setImageFormat("jpg");
$iMagick->stripImage();
$iMagick->writeImage($file);
$Imagick->clear();
```